# plaese suggest me regular expression for mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate month year in format `mm/yyyy` format. Please help me with a regular expression for this date format.

I have tried this, `/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])/(19|20)\d{2}$/`

But I'm not getting the right result.

Comment: `2\d|3[01]`?? Months only run to `12`, that looks like you're trying to do some form of *day* validation.

Comment: Why not use `split` at `/` then check the `mm` part and the `yyyy` part. Regex doesn't seem the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The initial part of your expression (the alternation) looks like a (flawed) *day* validation, not month.

Perhaps:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/
```

[Live Copy](http://regex101.com/r/eI0hS4)

That allows `01` through `09` (the first part of the alternation) and `10`, `11`, and `12` (the second part), then any year in the 20th or 21st centuries. Note the anchors both ends, and the backslash escaping the `/` in the middle.

Those capture groups seem a bit odd as well. If you just meant to do grouping, not *capture* groups, use non-capturing groups:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}$/
```

[Live Copy](http://regex101.com/r/mJ9mQ5)

Comment: @Sandip: Good deal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9])$
```

It will accept month as MM like '03' not '3'.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a regex, something like this is probably easier, both in understanding and maintainability (IMO).

Javascript

```
function isValidFormat(monthAndYear) {
    var parts = monthAndYear.split('/');

    return parts.length === 2 && parseInt(parts[0], 10) === +(parts[0]) && 
              parts[0] >= 1 && parts[0] <= 12 && parseInt(parts[1], 10) === +(parts[1]);
}

var tests = [
    '',
    ' ',
    '01/2014',
    '012013',
    'mm/yyyy',
    '01/yyyy',
    'mm/2014'];

tests.forEach(function (test) {
    console.log(test, isValidFormat(test))
});
```

Output

```
 false
  false
01/2014 true
012013 false
mm/yyyy false
01/yyyy false
mm/2014 false
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/y7kD3/)

If you want to be more strict with it then you can check the lengths of each part aswell.